# Tracking downloads of PDF from external sites

Tags: pdf, google-analytics

I have a site which hosts several PDFs which are often linked to directly from other websites.

I want to be able to track (preferably with Google Analytics) whenever anyone lands on a PDF page from an external site.

It would also be great if I could track whenever an external site's page loads up my PDF using an `<embed>` tag with my PDF URL as the `src` attribute.

The usual `_gaq.push` (etc) method (eg, [for this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829655/google-analytics-track-pdf-downloads)) doesn't work in this case because I can't modify the external sites.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You would need to do that on the backend of your website, by altering the requests to the PDFs to pass through a script that could update your own usage statistics.  You cannot use the standard frontend Google Analytics methods, as `<embed>` links do not touch your website, just the PDF.  GA is frontend only.

Comment: Thanks for comment Orbling. Do you have any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: Well, do you know how to make a script handle requests for binary files and pass them through transparently when requested?

Comment: You might be better off rolling up your server logs through something like Splunk.