# Document tracking with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google analytics track pdf downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829655/google-analytics-track-pdf-downloads)

Can I track documents with google analytics?

I tried just adding code to a webpage (below) linking to a document, but that gives me nothing...I'm left with believing all I can track is an HTML page with the google code

Code I attempted

```
http://www.whatever.com/TestDoc.doc?utm_source=blank&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=demo
```

As of now I can only see what people clock on in my site if the second=clicked page also has the Google script. But if it is just a PDF or DOC, I cannot see how many clicks there are!

Thanks!

Comment: Look into "event tracking". Link to the .doc must fire a GA javascript event.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics runs in the browser.  For this reason, links directly to the .doc can't be tracked like you're hoping above.  If you'd like to track downloads from links that are clicked on your page, Google Analytics on Steroids offers an easy _gasTrackDownloads hook for "event tracking" per @AllInOne's comment above.

Code Example:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gas = _gas || []; // _gas instead of _gaq
_gas.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-YYYYYY-Y']); // REPLACE WITH YOUR GA NUMBER
_gas.push(['_setDomainName', '.mydomain.com']); // REPLACE WITH YOUR DOMAIN
_gas.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gas.push(['_gasTrackForms']);
_gas.push(['_gasTrackOutboundLinks']);
_gas.push(['_gasTrackMaxScroll']);
_gas.push(['_gasTrackDownloads']); // track downloads
_gas.push(['_gasTrackYoutube', {force: true}]);
_gas.push(['_gasTrackVimeo', {force: true}]);
_gas.push(['_gasTrackMailto']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script');
ga.type = 'text/javascript';
ga.async = true;
ga.src = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gas/1.10.1/gas.min.js'; // new url
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

Link: [Google Analytics on Steroids](https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas)