# Custom reports showing download events in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Has anyone been able to include downloads within a custom report in Google analytics? I know I can get general/all events, but I just want downloads.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google analytics track pdf downloads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829655/google-analytics-track-pdf-downloads)

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking to track the `downloads` then you can add `_trackEvent` method in to the link that you want to track, like

```
Click <a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Demo', this.href]);" href="downloads/google_dynamic_map.zip">here</a> to download with demo.
```

Above code is from my working site and I'm able to track `download` of that file.

To view the report you can select the `Contents->Events` menu from the left nav bar of your google analytics page.

In my link `Downloads` is the `Event Category` and `Demo` is the `Event Action` and `this.href` is my `Event Label` which gives me the `url` of the file.

I've also created a custom report only to track `Downloads` event category from Google's custom report option and can track it from that custom report, filtered by `Downloads`.

### Screenshot of Custom Report settings

[image]

### Screenshot of standard report and viewing from `content` menu

[image]

**Useful links here:** [Link One](http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2011/04/how-to-track-downloads-in-google-analytics/) and [Link Two](http://gaconfig.com/google-analytics-event-tracking/) and [Event Tracking Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide).

**Update:** Also remember it'll take some time after you setup all of those things to track and see the result.

Comment: Is using events within custom reports no longer possible? http://imgur.com/w6azx51

Comment: Hawxby did you ever figure out the answer to that question? I'm wondering the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics on Steroids offers a great _gasTrackDownloads hook in their API if you don't already have the tracking code in place per @Sheikh's more accurate Custom Report answer above.

Code Example:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gas = _gas || []; // _gas instead of _gaq
_gas.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-YYYYYY-Y']); // REPLACE WITH YOUR GA NUMBER
_gas.push(['_setDomainName', '.mydomain.com']); // REPLACE WITH YOUR DOMAIN
_gas.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gas.push(['_gasTrackForms']);
_gas.push(['_gasTrackOutboundLinks']);
_gas.push(['_gasTrackMaxScroll']);
_gas.push(['_gasTrackDownloads']); // track downloads
_gas.push(['_gasTrackYoutube', {force: true}]);
_gas.push(['_gasTrackVimeo', {force: true}]);
_gas.push(['_gasTrackMailto']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script');
ga.type = 'text/javascript';
ga.async = true;
ga.src = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gas/1.10.1/gas.min.js'; // new url
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

Link: [Google Analytics on Steroids](https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas)